# SwiftUI How to share a URL to Facebook using FBSDKShareKit and ShareDialog?

Tags: swiftui, facebook-sdk-4.0, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable, fbsdksharekit

I tried looking for a solution in posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849084/how-to-sharedialog-facebook-cannot-working-in-swiftui) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66255656/sharing-an-url-and-text-to-facebook-or-twitter-in-swiftui) where people asked this very same question: How to share a url to Facebook using **SwiftUI**?

I even tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819360/swiftui-exporting-or-sharing-files) where somebody asked how to export a file using SwiftUI, but my problem is specifically with Facebook since I have no problem sharing urls to apps such as Whatsapp.
However, I found no answers...

## UIKit

By reading [Facebook's Developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), I found a way to share a post using UIKit.

I created a very simple sample project to make sure I understood the topic.
Here is the sample project in UIKit:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKShareKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func share(_ sender: UIButton) {
        shareLink(url: URL(string: "http://www.apple.com")!)
    }
    
    func shareLink(url: URL) {
        let content = ShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = url

        let dialog = ShareDialog(
            fromViewController: self,
            content: content,
            delegate: nil
        )
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Luckily, this worked right away.
By making this project work, I confirmed that I wasn't forgetting to link my AppBundleID to Facebook, or forgetting to add my FacebookAppID or any other needed files inside my info.plist.

## SwiftUI

I then tried to replicate the same project in SwiftUI to see if I could get it to work.
I used ViewControllerRepresentable to be able to include UIActivityViewController into SwiftUI.

The reason for using UIActivityViewController is because I want the user to choose where they want to share the URL (Whatsapp, Twitter, Facebook, etc).

Here is the code:

### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSharingView = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Share Link") {
            showSharingView.toggle()
        }
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSharingView) {
           ActivityViewController(activityItems: [URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/")!])
        }
    }
}
```

### UIViewControllerRepresentable

```
struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var activityItems: [URL]
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        
        controller.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType, completed, returnedItems, error) in
            
            if activityType == .postToFacebook {     
                shareLink(from: activityItems.first!)
            }
            
        }
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {}

    func shareLink(from url: URL) {
        
        // controller was created so I would have a UIViewControllerType to put as a parameter for fromViewController in ShareDialog, even though I don't think it fits
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        
        
        let content = ShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = url
        
        let dialog = ShareDialog(fromViewController: controller, content: content, delegate: nil)
        dialog.show()
    }
    
}
```

This code doesn't work because of what I assume is the `controller` variable used when initializing ShareDialog. (self doesn't work either because *"XCode cannot convert value of type 'ActivityViewController' to expected argument type 'UIViewController?'"*)

## Question

[Facebook Developer's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios) tells me that I need to write the following code in order to share a link:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com") else {
    // handle and return
}

let content = ShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = url

let dialog = ShareDialog(
    viewController: self, //<--this has been changed to 'fromViewController'
    content: content,
    delegate: self
)
dialog.show()
```

However, SwiftUI doesn't work with ViewControllers. How can I create a ViewController to use as a parameter in `fromViewController` in `ShareDialog` in order to successfully share my URL to Facebook?

Comment: Same question here for me.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like this,

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com") else {
    // handle and return
}

let content = ShareLinkContent()
content.contentURL = url

let dialog = ShareDialog(
    viewController: UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController,
    content: content,
    delegate: UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController
)
dialog.show()
```

Comment: Is this the optimal way rather than trying to create your own view controller? If so, why? I'm trying to get some understanding here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to share your url to facebook or any other Social media aplication

```
func shareToFacebook(videoURL: URL, description: String) {
        let activityItems: [Any] = [videoURL, description]
                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit to the question